# PHP wordpress get a multidimensional array of category objects

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

am trying to get all the categories on my wordpress as a heirarchial multidimensional array of objects of type category.
There are 2 functions in wordpress that kind of do what I want, but not exactly :

1) get_categories() - This one does return an array of category objects, which is great, but then the array is a flat one, where there is no differentiation between which category is a parent or which one is a child.

2) wp_list_categories() - which can return the categories with the herarchy intact, but problem is that the return value is html, and I need the categories to still be objects.

For example, if I had the following 3 trees as my parent-less categories :

```
/*
tree_stump

tree1
    branch1

tree2
    branch2
        twig2
            leaves2
            flowers2
            fruits2
*/
```

I am trying to get a return value which could be something like:

```
$cat_tree=array( 1=>$tree_stump,2=>array(1=>$tree1,2=>$branch1),3=>array(1=>$tree2,2=>array(1=>$branch2,2=>array($twig2,$leaves2,$flowers2,$fruits2  ) ) ) );
```

where each member of the multi dim array is still an object, and in all the child arrays, the first one is the parent of the rest of the members. I guess this would need some kinda recursive stuff - the stuff that gives me jitters !

Not sure if I made sense, please do let me know if I need to be more clear..
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my version which assumes $categories is the output of get_categories() but it doesn't matter what order they come in.

```
$cats_tree = get_cat_tree(0,$categories);
function get_cat_tree($parent,$categories) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($categories as $category){
        if ($parent == $category->category_parent) {
            $category->children = get_cat_tree($category->cat_ID,$categories);
            $result[] = $category;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is what i did:
First get an array using get_categories(). Then transform it into a new array.
I'm assuming that all children are below its parents in the original array.

```
$cats_tree = array();
foreach($categories as $category){
    $parent = $category->parent;
    if ( $parent && isset($cats_tree[$parent]) ){
        $cats_tree[$parent]->children[$category->cat_ID] = $category;
    }else{              
        $cats_tree[$category->cat_ID] = $category;
    }
}
```

Hope this is still useful for someone

Comment: This approach will fail if category nesting is more than 2 levels deep.  assume the following structure: parent[ID:1] > child[ID:2] > grandchild[ID:3].  which produces $cats_tree[1] = WP_Term->children[2] = WP_Term and produces $cats_tree[3] = WP_Term; (sorry for pseudocode)

Comment: 3rd levels end up appearing as siblings to top levels.  the recursive patrick64 answer works well though

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'hide_empty' => false,
);
$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
$categories = $the_query->get_terms();    

function get_cat_tree($parent,$categories) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($categories as $category){
        if ($parent == $category->parent) {
            $category->children = get_cat_tree($category->term_id,$categories);
            $result[] = $category;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$cats_tree = get_cat_tree(0,$categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

get_categories() returns an array with lots of properties you can use to build the array. namely `$category->category_parent` and `$category->parent`

Comment: thanks David, but I hope to get a bit more help, especially with the recursive bit.